# Extract Fourier coeffients from fft() in R

Tags: r, transform, fft, coefficients

I need to derive Fourier time series coefficients associated to (i-1)^th harmonic from fft() function in R, some idea?

For instance
Adding these concepts we get the general form of the Fourier Series:

f(t)=a_0+∑_k a_k×sin(kwt+ρ_k)

where a_0 is the DC component, w=2πf_0, where f_0 is the fundamental frequency of the original wave.

Each wave component a_k×sin(kwt+ρ_k) is also called a harmonic.

If I fixed the number of harmonics to 2, I would like to derive a_0,a_1,a_2 from fft()

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should be more specific. You should also provide an example of a data set your are using.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very general question. You can look here: [Fourier Transform: A R Tutorial](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/fourier/fourier.html), for a start.